# Read network files via php with authentication

Tags: php, authentication

I've a storage in the local network , it has a tree of folders contain files ..

I've a web server in another machine in the same network , Apache + PHP .

I need to access these files on the storage via a php script ..

I tried the following :

$data = file_get_contents("\\SomeServer\SomeFolder\test.txt");

I got

```
Warning: file_get_contents(\\SomeServer\SomeFolder\test.txt) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument
```

I tried to make the Apache runs with a login authentication which has an access to the storage folder , with no changes .

Any help ?

Comment: Try to use url like http : //server/somefolder/file.txt

Comment: I don't have a web server on that machine , it's just a storage , http doesn't make sense here .

Comment: $data = file_get_contents("//SomeServer/SomeFolder/test.txt");

Comment: \\SomeServer/SomeFolder/test.txt AND \\\\SomeServer\\SomeFolder\\test.txt , both are invalid , they returned the same error

Comment: Please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070545/php-read-file-contents-of-network-share-file

Comment: @Sandy : i tried to mount the folder to a local network drive , still no accessibility .

Comment: is it possible to copy file from that machine to your system with SCP?

Comment: @Sandy if so , i would make the web server is the host for the files and cancel the storage . Sure it doesn't make sense to copy the files .

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to read the file directly without mapping the drive access.

If server system has the LINUX environment then you have to mount the drive on server system and provided the drive letter name and then try to access the data.

IF Windows authentication to access network files, the HTTP server might not have the correct privileges so it returns permission denied.

This is what you can try:

- try accessing the file in windows explorer, if it prompts for username and password, then it could be a problem with authentication. try removing all restrictions and see if it works. then give ****apache service full rights to the directories being accessed***
- replace your backslashes with forward slashes
- make sure your directory names don't include spaces
- read the link http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=25805
- map the network resource to a drive name, see https://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/maintain/mapdrive.mspx

Note: The shared drive/folder provided must writing writes. As default only read rights are provided.

## *Settings Apache Service Full Rights

I am sure you have done the above things but you have not provided the full access rights to the apache server. Kindly do the following steps to provide the full access to apache server.

## global directory

setting in the httpd.conf

## Webiste vhosts

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
```

by default your global directory settings are:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

set the options to : Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

Finally, it should look like:

```
<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Server is windows - The folder is accessible with an AD user , by the way i tried to make Apache logs on with this account with no result - replaced the backslashes with forward one with no result - I mapped the folder to a network drive with no result as well .

Comment: @Ashraf Edited the post now seems your are missing this part and it will work now

Comment: @Ashraf Kindly let me know if didn't work now and if worked just accept the answer

Comment: Thanks for your instructions , still no results

Comment: @have to restarted the Apache after settings

Comment: then there must be another reason as it is working fine here with me