# PHP file() error, invalid argument

Tags: php, file

I have what should be a fairly straightforward operation, which gives me an error that doesn't seem very helpful.  The code is this:

```
<?php
$strLines = file('//tardis/htdocs/apps/freespace/FreeSpace-Servers.txt');
.
.
.
?>
```

But in php-errors.log, I get this:

> [28-Aug-2013 16:31:30] PHP Warning:  file(//tardis/htdocs/apps/freespace/FreeSpace-Servers.txt) [function.file]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\apps\freespace\freespace.php on line 2

The txt file is definitely there.  Any ideas what else an "Invalid argument" might suggest?  The documentation doesn't seem to hint at much of anything else.  Or, should I be doing this a different way?  My goal is to read the file in as an array of things.  All help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php read file contents of network share file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070545/php-read-file-contents-of-network-share-file) (try `\\\\server\\share\\file.txt`)

Comment: Similar, I see.  But fopen() is for URLs and file() is for UNC paths.  Still, it might work.  I'll try it, as a possible alternate option.

Comment: There's little difference, `file()` is just a wrapper around `fopen()`ing and `fread()`ing. [_"A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename."_](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Comment: Okay, I have moved the txt file to the htdocs folder, alongside my php page.  The code now reads:  `$strLines = fopen("http://tardis/apps/freespace/FreeSpace-Servers.txt", "r");` and I still get the invalid argument error  _[29-Aug-2013 12:47:55] PHP Warning:  fopen(\\tardis\htdocs\apps\freespace\FreeSpace-Servers.txt) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\apps\freespace\freespace.php on line 2_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using UNC, then the address should be

```
file('\\\\tardis\\htdocs\\apps\\freespace\\FreeSpace-Servers.txt');
```

You may also need to check that your PHP configuration allows you to open remote files.

Comment: That gives me the same error.

 [28-Aug-2013 17:11:22] PHP Warning:  file(\\tardis\htdocs\apps\freespace\FreeSpace-Servers.txt) [<a href='function.file'>function.file</a>]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\apps\freespace\freespace.php on line 2

Comment: Can you read any remote files?  My web host disabled this.  Check your PHP configuration.

Comment: I am starting to think it may be a PHP config issue, as you suggest.

Comment: I had the same issue when I tried opening a remote file. Took me forever to realize it was because my PHP config didn't allow remote file access.  If you're on a hosted site, then you're probably out of luck.  You could use wget or some other external command to retrieve the file to your local server and then read the file.

Comment: This seems like the most likely scenario at this point.  Thank you!  I think I will simply put the content of the text file into the PHP file, directly.  It's nowhere near as tidy, but it might be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat more correct answer than any of the above.  While all of the above is completely right, the actual problem (and solution) is detailed on question [18748985: PHP fails to read files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748985/php-fails-to-read-files).

The short answer is:  The Apache user password was changed, but Apache didn't know about it.  Update the password and restart the service.  The overall problem is slightly more colorful than that, but that's how the issue is most succinctly reduced.