# spring-boot spring.resources.static-locations: remote uri with linux

Tags: linux, spring-boot, resources

```
spring-boot 1.5.15.RELEASE
```

When use

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/resources/, file://192.168.11.130/
```

It works in windows but not in linux.
How can I change this by using `smb:/` or any other solution?

Comment: it is not relate to spring-boot, it just the simple java file read, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070545/php-read-file-contents-of-network-share-file

Comment: @clevertension But I need to use it in properties not in java code.

Comment: yes,but first you should mount the smb to your local folder,then you can configure in the properties

Comment: @clevertension Can't I use this remotely not use mount? Like file:/.

Comment: i think spring didn't support this as default, you can extend this feature by your own implementation with jcifs

Comment: @clevertension I think I don't have the ability to extend this. _(:з」∠)_ Thanks for your reply.